# Fortran runtime error while knitting rmd file

Tags: r

I have the below error for knitting my rmd file and I don't know what causes that.
Line 409 is a empty space between my context and a new chunk.

> At line 409 of file dsaupd.f Fortran runtime error: Actual string
>   length is shorter than the declared one for dummy argument 'which'
>   (1/2)

This is the code from line 408 to 412.

````
List names of the graph attributes:

```{r}

graph_attr_names(gr4)
````

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: I assume `dsaupd.f` is from Arpack [here](https://github.com/pv/arpack-ng/blob/master/SRC/dsaupd.f). You are probably calling the subroutine with an argument `which` that is not exactly length 2 as the error message tells you. The solution is obvious: change the call to a correct argument.

Comment: @Bhas thanks for your comment, but I didn't get what you mean. I add a part of code, hope that can help. I would really grateful if you explain more

Comment: I really couldn't tell you what is wrong; not enough information on your part.  I don't know a lot about `knitr` to even have a guess.